# What MySQL "DECIMAL" precision and scale is required to store a C# decimal value?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, floating-point, precision

I want to store some [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) values in my MySQL database. The obvious MySQL database type for that would be [DECIMAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) I guess.

What precision "a" and scale "b" do I have to set for DECIMAL(a,b ) exactly, to be able to represent/store the complete range of the C# decimal value type?

> In a DECIMAL column declaration, the precision and scale can be (and usually is) specified; for example:

```
salary DECIMAL(5,2)
```

> In this example, 5 is the precision and 2 is the scale. The precision represents the number of significant digits that are stored for values, and the scale represents the number of digits that can be stored following the decimal point.

From what I understand decimal can have up to 29 significant digits. The position of the decimal point depends on the actual value, or am I making a mistake here? That would mean I can have a worst case of either 29 digits before or 29 digits after the decimal separator.

So I would I assume , that I would have to use at least something like DECIMAL(58,29) to handle both cases in the database?

Comment: Good call. According to the docs indeed you would need DECIMAL(58,29) to be on the safe side. Otoh, you may have knowledge about the problem domain and can restrict the number of decimal places accordingly.

Comment: "Good call. According to the docs indeed you would need DECIMAL(58,29) to be on the safe side." @TaW share the doc link?

Comment: They're in the OP.

Comment: @TaW i do not read annything with the "safe DECIMAL(58,29)" numbers there.. The best i found was. "MySQL performs operations with a precision of 65 decimal digits, which should solve most common inaccuracy problems."  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html

Comment: Huh? So? .Net Decimal has 28-29 digits without specifying which side of the decimal point. And, of course this is not about operations only but about storage as well.

Comment: " .Net Decimal has 28-29 digits without specifying which side of the decimal point" Ok yes i see now in the .Net documentation then you should alteast use `DECIMAL(58,29)` i misunderstood @TaW

Comment: the storage size is documentated in MySQL documentation   "Values for DECIMAL (and NUMERIC) columns are represented using a binary format that packs nine decimal (base 10) digits into four bytes. Storage for the integer and fractional parts of each value are determined separately. Each multiple of nine digits requires four bytes, and the “leftover” digits require some fraction of four bytes. The storage required for excess digits is given by the following table. "  see source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html